# Anyone using Lisp for a MySQL-backended web app?

Tags: mysql, database, lisp

I keep hearing that Lisp is a really productive language, and I'm enjoying [SICP](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/classes/6.001/abelson-sussman-lectures/).  Still, I'm missing something useful that would let me replace PHP for server-side database interaction in web applications.

Is there something like PHP's [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) library for Lisp or Arc or Scheme or one of the dialects?

Comment: The most popular commercially used lisp dialect is currently Common Lisp (which is in many ways different from SICP's Scheme), and the CLSQL library works great with MySQL. It's very easy to set up using quicklisp(.org). I've used CLSQL in serious projects and it's reliable and very powerful (though I would recommend PostgreSQL with Postmodern as a better choice).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

newLisp has support for mysql5 and if you look at [the mysql5 function calls](http://www.newlisp.org/code/modules/mysql5.lsp.html), you'll see that it's close to PDO.

Answer (score 4):

Since nobody has mentioned it, you can try [Postmodern](http://common-lisp.net/project/postmodern/), which is an interface to PostgreSQL. It aims for a tighter integration with PostgreSQL and so doesn't pretend to portability between databases.

I've put it together with [hunchentoot](http://www.weitz.de/hunchentoot/) and [cl-who](http://weitz.de/cl-who/) and built a pretty nice website.

Comment: Postmodern is great, but the OP asked for MySQL, for which CLSQL is better suited (its ORM has support for more features but postmodern is cleaner and generally works better).

Answer (score 3):

newLISP - http://www.newlisp.org/ - has support for MySQL, but I haven't used it (newLISP).

Comment: Be forewarned.  If you're injto SICP, newLISP will disapoint you greatly.

Comment: Be doubly forewarned: SICP uses scheme, and most Lisp purists think that newLisp is really more a scheme than a Lisp...

Comment: Be triply forewarned: newLisp is barely a Lisp.

Answer (score 2):

If you're happy with SQL as part of your life, CL-SQL provides a mapping into CLOS objects. It appears to be more mature than Elephant.

I'm using it on my own website.

Answer (score 2):

I've had good success with SBCL and CL-SQL.  CL-SQL has a object mapping API, but I used the plain SQL API which simply returns lists and this worked well enough.  And in the Clojure language, you interact with JDBC through a maps or structs {:col1 "a", :col2 "b"}, so a generated class library doesn't get you any simpler code, the language handles it nicely.  In my experience, there is less cruft between lisp and sql than between more static languages and sql.

Answer (score 2):

our Common Lisp ORM solution is http://common-lisp.net/project/cl-perec/

the underlying SQL lib is http://common-lisp.net/project/cl-rdbms/ (fully tested with PostgreSQL, has a toy SQlite backend and a somewhat tested Oracle backend)

we started out using CLSQL, but after some struggle we decided to roll our own.

these libs and PostgreSQL are used in a clustered web application developed for the Hungarian government for planning the budget of the municipalities. it has about 4000 users, 500 at peek time. a little more info is available at http://common-lisp.net/project/cl-dwim/

Comment: sadly there are no examples how to use it :-(

Comment: hu.dwim.perec has an extensive test suite, and many of the other hu.dwim.* libs, too.

Answer (score 1):

Cliki is a good resource for Common Lisp libraries:
http://www.cliki.net/database

There is a project named Elephant (http://common-lisp.net/project/elephant/index.html), which is an abstraction for object persistence in CL.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you're switching your Webapp on Lisp, consider using persistence: you now have a constantly running Lisp image that holds everything about your application. I personnally used [Elephant](http://www.common-lisp.net/project/elephant) for that.

Elephant can use CL-SQL or BDB as it's backend, which means that you can use MySQL if you have one running. I found using SQLite really practical, though.

Answer (score 0):

We use SBCL, UCW, CL-SQL and MySQL as our back-end for [Paragent.com](http://paragent.com). It has worked very well for us. We also have a number of clients using UCW/CL-SQL/MySQL for custom sites we have built them through our consulting arm [Bitfauna](http://bitfauna.com).