# What are the best practices for functional programming and database interaction?

Tags: database, orm, functional-programming, lisp, crud

I know that in pure object-oriented languages like Java it usually makes sense to use ORMs like Hibernate. But what would I do when writing a CRUD-type functionality in Clojure or Common LISP?

Passing around SQL as the first-order functions? But isn't having SQL in HTML-generating code very ugly?

Thanks,

Olek

Answer (score 3):

Common Lisp is not a self-consciously FP language.  Clojure can just use Hibernate.

For Common Lisp: [databases](http://www.cliki.net/database).  Here's a [persistent object one](http://common-lisp.net/project/elephant/).  And [here](http://roeim.net/vetle/docs/cl-webapp-intro/part-1/) is the first part of a tutorial that uses it with Hunchentoot, a CL webserver and dynamic webpage toolkit.  SQL in CL [can look like this](http://clsql.b9.com/manual/ch02s02.html) (which looks longer than it really is, because the SQL is horizontally formatted and the CL isn't).  And if you like, [this guy](http://github.com/tomoyuki28jp) is working on a web framework (using CLSQL and Elephant, already linked-to) that aims at tersity, with an eye on the arc challenge.

EDIT: [a recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556456/is-it-feasible-to-do-serious-web-development-in-lisp/556618#556618) expands on this.

Comment: CL-SQL is really nice, and shows how object-oriented and functional can work together.

Answer (score 1):

Ur/Web may be interesting, although it's not lisp based: http://plv.csail.mit.edu/ur/

As quoted from their site:

> Ur/Web supports construction of dynamic web applications backed by SQL databases. The signature of the standard library is such that well-typed Ur/Web programs "don't go wrong" in a very broad sense. Not only do they not crash during particular page generations, but they also may not:
>
> - Suffer from any kinds of code-injection attacks
> - Return invalid HTML
> - Contain dead intra-application links
> - Have mismatches between HTML forms and the fields expected by their handlers
> - Include client-side code that makes incorrect assumptions about the "AJAX"-style services that the remote web server provides
> - Attempt invalid SQL queries
> - Use improper marshaling or unmarshaling in communication with SQL databases or between browsers and web servers

Answer (score 0):

an alternative set of Common Lisp tools is described in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64953/anyone-using-lisp-for-a-mysql-backended-web-app/78735#78735)